# Python Searching for Specific Entry

Tags: python, json

So I have the code;

```
names= [index + " - " + js[index]["name"] for index in js]
```

To search through this data:

```
{ "1": {"name":"One"} },
{ "2": {"name":"Two"} },
{ "3": {"name":"Three"} },
```

How could I change it so I could set a variable to 2 earlier in the program and make the code only search for the name of 2?

Comment: You are not searching at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming js is a valid dict:

```
js = { "1": {"name":"One"},
       "2": {"name":"Two"},
       "3": {"name":"Three"}}
```

You are building a list with all the values of "name". If you only want those indexes, where "name" equals "Two", include it in your list comprehension:

```
>>> needle = "Two"
>>> names = ["{} - {}".format(index, js[index]["name"]) for index in js if js[index]["name"]==needle]

>>> print(names)
['2 - Two']
```

**EDIT**: Regarding your comment, if you try to get the value "Two" for the key "2", you can directly access the dict the usual way:

```
>>> needle="2"
>>> js[needle]["name"]
'Two'
```

In this specific, simplified case it would be easier to use a flat dictionary:

```
js = { "1": "One",
       "2": "Two",
       "3": "Three"}
```

The access ("search") would then be:

```
>>> js[needle]
'Two'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's been helpful. I was actually trying to ask how to search for "2", and return Two.